# RDLC Detail pairs

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc

in and RDLC, on a table each row of info is displayed as two RDLC details rows.

ie

```
Bob    1234 bobo st      512-512-5122
Jones  Austin Tx, 78660  512-512-5133
```

but when paginating the report, the data pairs get split, with "bob" on one page and "Jones" on another.

Is there any way to force the RDLC Generator to keep these pairs on the same page?

Thanks,

Eric-

Comment: I have the same issue...did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Tablix properties
- select General
- select Page break option
- Mark Keep together on one page if possible